# Network Location Awareness Not Working Correctly

Tags: windows-server-2016

I have 2 domain controllers running Server 2016 and all using Static DNS records. When domain joined computers connect to the network they show as being connected to an Unidentified Network instead of a Domain network. In most cases I have to disable the adapter and re-enable it to get the Domain back. Is there anything I can do to fix this or where to even troubleshoot to figure out why it isn't seeing the domain first?

Comment: If the computers have static IP addresses, what are you expecting should be 'updated'? Or do you mean the computers are not *creating* A records.

Comment: They are creating A records but when they connect they show the network as Unidentified Network instead of the Domain they should be on.

Comment: That's not a function of the DNS A records. That's a function of NLA. - https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/networking/2010/09/08/network-location-awareness-nla-and-how-it-relates-to-windows-firewall-profiles/

Comment: @JukEboX: The question should be modified to state only that the computers are showing an unidentified network, and remove the DNS speculation.

Comment: @GregAskew have done so right now.

Comment: This post suggests that a "race" condition is the culprit and that setting the NLA service to Automatic (Delayed) startup will fix it. - https://newsignature.com/articles/network-location-awareness-service-can-ruin-day-fix/

Comment: @joeqwerty That was not the issue. I have tried those fixes but did nothing.